# d3 - v5 text rendering slower than v3.5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have migrated my d3 tree from v3.5 to v5. Now I find that there is considerable lag with the v5 version when performing a search on the tree using [Patrick Brockmann’s search and highlight functionality](http://bl.ocks.org/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23).

The lag shows when doing a search with the drop-down Select2. All leaf nodes are not expanding fast enough that results in a mass of black text for a few seconds in the v5 version.  This doesn't happen in the v3.5 version.

[image]

Any ideas how this could be optimised to get the same performance as the v3.5 version of the tree?  The JSON data in both versions is the same.

[d3 v3.5 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2qu08fh/)

[d3 v5 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0qtfr3h/3/)

Code from the search functionality (same for both v3.5 and v5 versions):

```
            function select2DataCollectName( d ) {
                if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( select2DataCollectName );
                else if ( d._children )
                    d._children.forEach( select2DataCollectName );
                if ( !d.children && d.data.type == 'learning_event' ) select2Data.push( d.data.name );
            }

            //===============================================
            function searchTree( d ) {
                if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( searchTree );
                else if ( d._children )
                    d._children.forEach( searchTree );
                var searchFieldValue = eval( searchField );
                if ( searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.toLowerCase().match( searchText.toLowerCase() ) ) {
                    // Walk parent chain
                    var ancestors = [];
                    var parent = d;
                    while ( parent !== null && typeof ( parent ) !== "undefined" ) {
                        ancestors.push( parent );
                        //console.log(parent);
                        parent.class = "found";
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                }
            }

            //===============================================
            function clearAll( d ) {
                d.class = "";
                if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( clearAll );
                else if ( d._children )
                    d._children.forEach( clearAll );
            }
            //===============================================
            function collapse( d ) {

                if ( d.children ) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    //set the parent object in all the children
                    d._children.forEach( function ( d1 ) {
                        d1.parent = d;
                        collapse( d1 );
                    } );
                    d.children = null;
                }
            }
            //===============================================
            function collapseAllNotFound( d ) {
                if ( d.children ) {
                    if ( d.class !== "found" ) {
                        d._children = d.children;
                        d._children.forEach( collapseAllNotFound );
                        d.children = null;
                    } else
                        d.children.forEach( collapseAllNotFound );
                }
            }
            //===============================================
            function expandAll( d ) {
                if ( d._children ) {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d.children.forEach( expandAll );
                    d._children = null;
                } else if ( d.children )
                    d.children.forEach( expandAll );
            }

            //===============================================
            // Toggle children on click.
            function toggle( d ) {
                if ( d.children ) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                clearAll( root );
                update( d );
                $( "#search" ).select2( "val", "" );
            }

            //===============================================
            $( "#search" ).on( "select2-selecting", function ( e ) {
                clearAll( root );
                expandAll( root );
                update( root );
                searchField = "d.data.name";
                searchText = e.object.text;
                searchTree( root );
                root.children.forEach( collapseAllNotFound );
                update( root );
            } )


    var colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["MD", "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4"])
        .range(["#abacab", "#53e28c", "#4b80fa", "#eab014", "#bd57fe"]);

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 0},
    width = 2000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" +
            margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



    var i = 0,
        duration = 750,
        root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
        return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);


    select2Data = [];
                select2DataCollectName( root );
                select2DataObject = [];
                select2Data.sort( function ( a, b ) {
                        if ( a > b ) return 1; // sort
                        if ( a < b ) return -1;
                        return 0;
                    } )
                    .filter( function ( item, i, ar ) {
                        return ar.indexOf( item ) === i;
                    } ) // remove duplicate items
                    .filter( function ( item, i, ar ) {
                        select2DataObject.push( {
                            "id": i,
                            "text": item
                        } );
                    } );
                $( "#search" ).select2( {
                    placeholder: "Select a Learning Event...",
                    data: select2DataObject,
                    containerCssClass: "search"
                } );
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the collapse, but I do see it with the expand.  What I am seeing is that, on the collapse, the words are dimming as the collapse occurs, but on the expand, the words appear at full intensity immediately, before the tree expands.

Comment: Yes, that is more correct.

Comment: To be clear, the nodes move at exactly the same rate in both examples.  The difference is in the way the text is rendered on expand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is clickbait, since there isn't any difference in performance between the two versions. Makes it sound like you're reporting a regression. :)

As @RobertHarvey points out, the difference is that the text doesn't fade in from transparent when it enters. Looks like you missed `fill-opacity` when porting your code from D3v3 to D3v5

```
    nodeEnter.append('text')
      // ...
      .style( "fill-opacity", 1e-6 )
```

and

```
    var nut = nodeUpdate.transition()
    // ...
    nut.select( "text" )
      .style( "fill-opacity", 1 );
```

[Fork of your d3v5 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/sepknumw/7/).

Comment: Well sometimes it is a challenge to get attention around here ;)   But there is a question mark at the end of the question title...  I will check my code and get back

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which reduces the visibility of the lag compared to the v3.5 version, but nevertheless, the lag is still noticeable and appears to be a regression from 3.5 where no text transition is apparent on expansion in that fiddle.

Comment: I don't see any difference in performance between the two versions, or lag on either version. I have tested Chrome, Firefox and Safari on an iMac. Maybe check for other factors like having developer tools open or something.

Comment: Mmm. it does appear acceptable in Chrome (FF is my default).  I will test on another computer with FF....might be some FF plugins.

Comment: Opened your fiddle on another computer using FF, 73.0.1 and the lag is quite noticeable and not visible on the v3.5 fiddle.

Comment: I was on FF74 developer edition, just tried out FF33. I still don't see any difference in performance, so either it's really subtle or it's not visible on this computer (fast with lots of RAM). It's more likely to do with changes you made while porting, than any change in D3. Signing out.

Comment: OK, I have accepted your answer as it solves the problem for the most part. The lag was noticeable enough to do a screen shot of the text in transition in your fiddle....